# How does ActiveRecord implement `:if => ...` on validations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I've been looking through the ActiveRecord source to find out how `:if => proc_or_method_name` works on ActiveRecord validations, but the only instances of `:if` in the source are in the comments explaining how the feature should be called.

For example, you can have a line like the following in a model:

```
validates_presence_of :name, :if => :nameable?
```

and the validation only gets checked if the `nameable?` method returns a truthy value for the given model.

Where is this functionality actually defined, as I can't find this behaviour anywhere in the (Rails2) source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:if` option is checked for in the file `activesupport\lib\active_support\callbacks.rb`.

The method `should_run_callback` is called to check if the callback should be executed or not.

Look also at how the callback chain is processed, starting from the `run_callbacks` method in the same file.

Some code from v2.3.8 of that file is:

```
def should_run_callback?(*args)
  [options[:if]].flatten.compact.all? { |a| evaluate_method(a, *args) } &&
  ![options[:unless]].flatten.compact.any? { |a| evaluate_method(a, *args) }
end
```

And here is how I found out (in case anyone is interested):

1. Downloaded Rails v2.3.8 from github and unzipped it.
2. grepp'ed for `:if` in all .rb files
3. In a `activerecord/CHANGELOG`, located a comment that mentioned:

   *Added the :if option to all validations that can either use a block or a method pointer to determine whether the validation should be run or not. #1324 [Duane Johnson/jhosteny].*
4. Google'd for that comment. Found it in a [google cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aMk9My3UiGHEJ%3adev.rubyonrails.org/log/trunk/activerecord/test/validations_test.rb%3Flimit%3D100%26rev%3D2863%26mode%3Dstop_on_copy%26format%3Dchangelog+%22all+validations+that+can+either+use+a+block+or+a+method+pointer+to+determine+whether%22&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=firefox-a).
5. Found that the comment/addition was made on 05/21/05 10:57:18 by david
6. Located date 2005-05-21 on [rails github history on page 546](https://github.com/rails/rails/commits/master?page=546):
7. Got an inkling of how the `:if` works
8. Found that the code that commit referred to was no longer existing in v2.3.8. had to find latest location of that code
9. grepp'ed `:if` again and went though each file that felt "good". came to `activesupport/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb`
10. searched for `:if` in the file and it was found in only one location, in the method `should_run_callback`.
11. Posted answer
12. Crossed fingers and waited for bounty. :D

That was fun!

Answer (score 3):

As of Rails 3, ActiveRecord callbacks are defined in [active_record/callbacks.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.3/activerecord/lib/active_record/callbacks.rb), but because an ActiveRecord model inherits from ActiveModel, then you should also look at the [active_model/callbacks.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb) file.

The Callback feature itself is a separate component. In fact, ActionController before/after filters are callbacks, actually.
For this reason, the callback system is a module defined in [ActiveSupport::Callbacks](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v3.0.3/activemodel/lib/active_model/callbacks.rb).

Merge altogether these 3 pieces and you get the ActiveRecord callbacks feature.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply. I actually meant Rails2 but apart from the separation into ActiveModel I don't think that's an issue here. I've updated the question with more information because I've given the wrong impression.